# Getting names and or types of variables in java possible?

Tags: java

In my application, i want to print out a variable´s value AND its name, if possible.

For example:

```
int testinteger = 0;
String type = > type of testinteger? (int);
String name = > name of testinteger? (testinteger);


System.out.println("The "+type+" "+name+" has a value of"+ testinteger);
```

So i want to read: The int testinteger has a value of 0

Unfortunately, i suppose, it is not possible with primitive types. But is it also the case for types like `String`, `Integer`, `Boolean` etc.? Is there any possibility to get it?

Comment: You should really explain why you want to to this.

Comment: @Curtos I don't think it's a duplicate of that question. In this question the *local identifier* in question is in scope and used in scope only. Basically it is asking if it is possible to do `nameOf identifier -> String` or `typeOf identifier -> TypeOrClass`.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen I think that's closer to a duplicate, but the premise of that question still hinges on "reflection". If Java *did* support such `nameOf/typeOf` operators (which it does not), they would operate on the compile-time information and be independent of reflection (much like `obj.class`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this; however, you could use a `Map<String,String>` to do it in non-dynamic way.  The keys would be the type + variable name (you would have to hard code them), and the values would be the actual values associated with those variables (in string form, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Getting a variable name is difficult, but if you use `Integer` instead of `int`, you could do something like:

```
Integer testInteger = 1;
String type = testInteger.class.getName();
System.out.println(type);
```

If you stick to using classes, and not primitives, you can take advantage of class literals - that is, the `.class` variable of every object.